# No welcome email sent when users register via profile2 registration path

Tags: users

I am using profile2 registration path for two different types of roles. The roles are auto-assigned when users register via one of the paths. I have used mail logger to check and the emails are not sent. Other types of emails are sent. I can block the new users then unblock them and registration emails are sent.

When a user is registered via the regular user registration (/user/register) an email is sent.

I am using Drupal core 7.59, profile2 7.x-1.4, profile2 registration path 7.x-1.13.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but have not been able to track down the cause yet. Appears to be a bug in the Profile2 module.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the profile2 module. I've created a patch for another issue and this, in turn, has fixed the no emails sent issue I was experiencing.

For a patch and proposed solution please see: https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2/issues/1993770#comment-12699962